# Jsoup is not connecting after a re-setup

Tags: jsoup

```
response=Jsoup.connect(productURL).followRedirects(true).execute();
```

I have used the above code to connect to jsoup and it was working fine. Recently my IT admin has rebuild my PC with Windows 8 32 bit OS to increase the performance as I am suffering from low performance issues.

Now the `connect()` method is throwing a socket exception. I have checked my environment and found the only change is jdk 8: earlier it was 9.

Could you please help me to sort-out the issue?

Comment: Post your code and error message.

Comment: I am getting error while just connecting, as below try {
     response=Jsoup.connect(productURL).timeout(5000).followRedirects(true).execute();
    // Document document = Jsoup.connect(productURL).get();
    }catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    }, and the error is -  socket exception,

Comment: I found that earlier I used java 9 64 bit and its now 8 32 bit as my OS degraded, is that any impact?